# How to exposure spring boot actuator endpoints without using application.properties file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

How can I enable and exposure actuator endpoints in Spring boot 2.5.8 application if I don't have access to `application.properties` file?

It's easy to do with `application.properties` file, just configuring

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`

But if I don't have access to `application.properties`, how can I do it in code?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the properties as environment variables. Just need to switch casing and `.` to `_`

`MANAGEMENT_ENDPOINTS_WEB_EXPOSURE_INCLUDE=*`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Do you know how to configure it in the code? Is there some customizer or something like this? (like WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> customizer for embedded Tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

You can use command line to do the same.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments='Dmanagement.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*'
```

Comment: Alien, thanks for idea. But when I had to configure Spring boot embedded tomcat, I used WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> bean in my code. Here I'd like  some similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found 2 solutions.

1. To use SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties() method before run application:

   ```
   public class MyApplication {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
           app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("management.endpoints.web.exposure.include", "*"));
           app.run(args);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Second approach requires access to properties file.

To open properties file with PropertiesConfiguration (this class can both: read properties from file and write new properties/values to file).
Checked if property already exist
If not exist - add it.

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = getConfig(filePathToPropertiesFile);
if (null == config.getString("management.endpoints.web.exposure.include")) {
    config.setProperty("management.endpoints.web.exposure.include", "*");
    config.save();
}
```

All this actions also need to perform in main method before application run.